# Limiting left join hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, playframework, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

I have an entity called ServiceList that has set of productListOrders

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="service_lists")
 public class ServiceList implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Set<ProductServiceListOrder> productServiceListOrders = new HashSet<ProductServiceListOrder>();
}

ProductServiceListOrder looks like this 
public class ProductServiceListOrder implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private ServiceList serviceList;
private Product product;
private Date createdAt;

private Long id;
private Integer internalOrder;
}
```

The trick is in internalOrder which the highest internalOder value showed first .. 
when I do my hibernate query I do like this ...

```
{
List<ServiceList> lists = (List<ServiceList>) JPA.em().createQuery(
                    "select  distinct list from com.vionlabs.movieoncloud.model.main.ServiceList list " +
                            "left join fetch list.productServiceListOrders "  )
}
```

**MY QUESTION IS** :- I want to set a limit on left join that means I want to get only the highest 10 productSeriveListOrders when I do the query ... How I can do this .... any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

On the `Query` object returned by the `createQuery` method of your `entityManager` you can use the method `setMaxResult` and use this in conjunction with an order by on your query.